# Identifying component from multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my App.js file, I am adding two components called `<Clock />`, inside Clock I am able to select a country and its time difference. The Clock component has a state called value, in my App.js I want to return the sum of both of these offsets when selected, but I'm not sure how best to do this?

I have passed a state down to the Clock component from App.js, but am still unsure how I can identify which Clock has been update and therefore when to rerun the sum function.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be great

Sorry here's the code...

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Clock from './components/Clock';

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="pa4">
        <Clock />
        <Clock />
        <h4>HERE WOULD BE THE TIME DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE TWO CLOCKS</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**components/Clock.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Face from './clock/Face';

// Country select start
class Clock extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 0,
      data: {zones: []}
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://api.timezonedb.com/v2/list-time-zone?key=6KFSXAA33B1V&format=json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({data: json}));    
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(
      {
        value: event.target.value
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const zones = this.state.data.zones;
    const countries = zones.map((country) =>
      <option key={zones.indexOf(country)} value={country.gmtOffset}>
        {country.countryName}
      </option>
    )
    const gmtOffset = this.state.value / 60 / 60;

    return (
      <div className="w-third ">
        <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {countries}
        </select>
        <Face timeDiff={gmtOffset} />
        <h3 className="td">{gmtOffset}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Clock;
```

My apologies for the messy code, first attempt at an app and trial errors went a little overboard in places

Comment: What is the code of `Clock` ? Or what is the package (library) that you are using to reuse `Clock`

Comment: Could you please show us the code and it would be better .

Comment: If you need sum - why do you want to identify Clock?

Answer (score 1):

You could lift up the state :

Store the state of both `Clock`s in you `App` component. Update it by giving a prop to your clocks which triggers a callback in your `App`:

Inside your App class:

```
handleClock1Changed(time) {
  this.setState({
    clock1Time: time,
  });
}

handleClock2Changed(time) {
  this.setState({
    clock2Time: time,
  });
}

[...]

<Clock onChange={value => this.handleClock1Changed(value)} />
<Clock onChange={value => this.handleClock2Changed(value)} />
```

In your Clock :

```
<select
  onChange={() => {
    this.handleChange();
    this.props.onChange(this.state.value);
  }} >
    {countries}
</select>
```

In detail here : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html